# Power BI - Can't Display Fields if One isn't Aggregated

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop

My relationships in Power BI, look like this:

```
Table A has a 1 to 1 relationship with table B, cross filtering in both directions.
Table B (my bridge table) has a many to 1 relationship with table C, cross filtering in both directions.
Table C has a Many to 1 relationship with table D, cross filtering in both directions.
```

If I go to build a table visual using columns from Tables A and D, I have to have the one of the ID columns aggregated otherwise, if it's missing or not aggregated, it will throw an error about not being able to determine the relationship.

Why is this and how do I solve it?

Comment: Show some sample data from you all 4 tables and then add your expected output.